# Pointers to a typed variable in C#: Interface, Generic, object or Class? (Boxing/Unboxing)

Tags: c#, variables, pointers, boxing, typed

First of all, I apologize if this has been asked a thousand times. I read my C# book, I googled it, but I can't seem to find the answer I am looking for, or I am missing the point big time.

I am very confused with the whole boxing/unboxing issue. Say I have fields of different classes, all returning typed variables (e.g. 'double') and I would like to have a variable point to any of these fields. In plain old C I would do something like:

```
double * newVar;
newVar = &oldVar;
newVar = &anotherVar;
...
```

I have a timer calls a function and passes the value of the referenced variable:

```
ChartPlotData(*newVar);
```

The reason why I am looking for a pointer is because newVar changes at runtime, linked to an Event:

```
public void checkbox_Clicked(object sender ...)
  if (sender == checkbox1) value = &object1.field1;
  if (sender == checkbox2) value = &object2.field1;
```

How can this be done in C#?

EDIT1: Explained purpose of referencing.

EDIT2: Made some incorrect statements, deleted them and shortened the question.

Comment: What's the purpose of such referencing?

Comment: What does this sentence mean?  "In C#, it seems I could do an interfase, but would require that all fields be properties and named the same. Breaks apart when one of the properties doesn't have the same name or is not a property."

Comment: I could force objects to implement an interface, but this means that I would need to create a property common to all objects that might make no sense. For example, a class 'Car' could have a 'NrWheels' property, while a 'Boat' class would have a 'NrPropellers' property. If at runtime, I wish to call Plot(NrRotatingDevices), I could possibly create a interface 'NrRotatingDevices' but would have to modify both classes to implement this interface or rename NrPropellers and NrWheels to NrRotatingDevices.

Comment: Rephrased question and deleted incorrect statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a click event, as suggested in your edit, and then use a delegate to select the data to be passed to the control. I'm not sure if that'll meet your performance requirements though.

```
ChartPlotData(valueSelector());

// ...

Func<double> valueSelector;

protected void Checkbox_Click(object sender /* ... */)
{
    if (sender == checkbox1) valueSelector = () => object1.field1;
    if (sender == checkbox2) valueSelector = () => object2.field1;
    // ...
}
```

(If you preferred, and if you're able to, you could overload your `ChartPlotData` method to accept a `Func<double>` rather than a plain `double`, and then invoke the selector delegate lazily inside the method rather than at the call site.)

Answer (score 0):

Simple types and structs are of value type in C#. You can't do anything about it unless as you mentioned you use unsafe modifier. Having said that, your options are limited.

1. Use object instead of primitive types.
2. Use arrays of size 1.
3. Custom generic proxy class encapsulating either of above.
4. ???

Comment: If you're going to use a generic proxy class you should just box/unbox the value, as that's what you're effectively doing anyway.

Comment: @yodaj007: right, proxy is storing the value type. However now since it's a class you can pass it by reference, e.g. 
VTP<double> d = new VTP<double>(1.2); 
VTP<double> d1 = d; 
See the same in petro.sidlovskyy's response.
d1.Value = 3.1; 
assert(d.value == 3.1);

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to an existing value type using the [`ref` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

```
public static void ModifyNumber(ref int i)
{
    i += 1;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int num = 4;
    ModifyNumber(ref num);
    ModifyNumber(ref num);
    ModifyNumber(ref num);
    ModifyNumber(ref num);


    // num now equals 8


}
```

Comment: In C, this is the same as Function(&variable1) but if you wanted to point to variable2, you would need to call Function(&variable2). I wish to do Function(pVariable), where 'double * pVariable' and variable gets assigned at runtime.

Comment: Paul, this isn't C anymore.  This is C#.  Things are done differently here.

Comment: Yoda, this is why I am here asking how to do it. Sorry if my explanations are not clear, but your answers are not helping either.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you need address of the variable. Double is value type and is stored in stack. To pass it by refference into the method just use C# ref keyword.

From cases you have mentioned I personally would prefer something like this:

```
class Program
{
    public class Refferenced<T> where T : struct 
    {
        public T Value { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Refferenced<double> x = new Refferenced<double>();
        Refferenced<double> y = new Refferenced<double>();
        y.Value = 2;
        x = y;
        x.Value = 5;
        Console.WriteLine(x.Value);
        Console.WriteLine(y.Value);
        y.Value = 7;
        Console.WriteLine(x.Value);
        Console.WriteLine(y.Value);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

It is similar to C# NullAble types.

Comment: The reason is that I am trying to get the max speed I can from a charting tool and the reference to the typed value that the tool needs to plot changes at runtime. I am trying to avoid the overhead of boxing/unboxing objects every time I call the plot function.

Comment: An instance of `double` might not be stored on the stack.

Comment: @PaulG: In case you use generics you will not have boxing/unboxing. Also you should remember that propety getter or setter is method call so if you need the best performance you may replace property (Value) with simple field. Also you may make this generic class sealed.